# Why does AsyncLocal<T> propagate to child threads whereas ThreadLocal<T> does not?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have had to replace the usage of ThreadLocal in my code with AsyncLocal so that the 'ambient state' is maintained when awaiting async operations.

However, an annoying behaviour of AsyncLocal is that it is 'flowed' to child threads. This is different to ThreadLocal. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<string> ThreadState = new ThreadLocal<string>();
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<string> AsyncState = new AsyncLocal<string>();

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        ThreadState.Value = "thread";
        AsyncState.Value = "async";

        await Task.Yield();

        WriteLine("After await: " + ThreadState.Value); 
        WriteLine("After await: " + AsyncState.Value); // <- I want this behaviour

        Task.Run(() => WriteLine("Inside child task: " + ThreadState.Value)).Wait(); // <- I want this behaviour
        Task.Run(() => WriteLine("Inside child task: " + AsyncState.Value)).Wait();
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever find a solution? My ambient state object is not thread-safe, so I can't risk it "flowing" to client threads, but I need to maintain it across async/await operations.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`AsyncLocal` stores the data in the execution context, which is automatically flown by most APIs (including `Task.Run`).

One way to prevent that is to explicitly suppress flow whenever needed:

```
using (ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
{
    Task.Run(...);
}
```

Comment: Does the fact that the AsyncLocal data is flown by Task.Run mean it should be 'thread safe'? Whereas this was not required as TaskLocal would (and could) only be accessed by a single thread?

Comment: What else is lost in doing this though?

Answer (score 1):

*(Not an answer, just a workaround I found - too long for a comment.)*

Rather than suppressing the flow of the complete execution context, as suggested by Kevin's answer, you can manually reset the value of your non-thread-safe ambient context object in your child thread. This will *not* reset the value in your main thread:

```
private static readonly AsyncLocal<string> AsyncState = new AsyncLocal<string>();

static async Task Main()
{
    AsyncState.Value = "async";

    WriteLine($"Main before await: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}/{AsyncState.Value}");

    await Task.Yield();

    WriteLine($"Main after await: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}/{AsyncState.Value}");

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        WriteLine($"Child: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}/{AsyncState.Value}");

        AsyncState.Value = "async-modified";

        WriteLine($"Child: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}/{AsyncState.Value}");
    }).Wait();

    WriteLine($"Main after child: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}/{AsyncState.Value}");
}
```

yields

```
Main before await: 1/async
Main after await: 3/async
Child: 3/async
Child: 3/async-modified
Main after child: 3/async
```

So even though "Main after await" and the child thread happen to use *the same thread pool thread* (3), modifying AsyncState in the child task doesn't affect the value in the Main context.